# Who was King Bradley supposed to be?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In Fullmetal Alchemist (2003 anime series) Fuhrer Bradley/King Bradley is a homunculus and is head of the military in Central. They say the Homunculi are created when an alchemist attempts human transmutation, which always fails and from those failures, a homunculus is created and is born to look like whoever they were suppose to be bought back as.

> e.g. Alphonse and Ed tried to resurrect Trisha, their mother, and end up failing. Years later they run into her but she is known as Miss Douglas.

I can't remember how I know that Homunculi are suppose to look like what they were supposed to be resurrected as but what was King Bradley supposed to be?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the 2003 anime, instead of the manga/Brotherhood continuities?

Comment: Yeah. Not brotherhood.

Comment: Hmmmm I don't think they actually explained the origins of a number of the homunculi, but I'll probably double check on the internet as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take my shot at an answer. In the 2003 continuity, homunculi are created when alchemists attempt human transmutation, as you stated earlier. This more or less explains the origins of:

- Wrath, who was created by Izumi
- Sloth, who, as you stated, was created by the Elric brothers
- Envy, who was Hohenheim's son
- Lust, who was created by Scar's brother

Given this "rule" and the examples in the anime, it's at the very least implied that the resulting homunculus from a human transmutation will resemble, at least to a degree, the original intended result of the transmutation.

I don't recall the series explaining the origins of Gluttony, Greed, or Pride, though according to the fan-made Fullmetal Alchemist Wiki, they were all created by Dante. In [the case of Gluttony](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Gluttony), this seems to have been done for the purpose of creating philosopher's stones, at least according to the FMA Wiki (which may or may not be a reliable source). In the case of Pride, it would make sense to a degree for the homunculus to have been created as a means to control the government for Dante's purposes, but it seems that neither the purpose of creating Pride nor his origins are ever explicitly stated in the 2003 series.

Comment: Yes, Gluttony was created to make more Philosopher's Stones. Dante was also responsible for the creation of Pride and Greed, but the specifics of these creations are not known.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know is.....

- Wrath was Izumi's child
- Sloth was Ed and Al's mom
- Envy was Hohenheim's son
- Greed from what I can tell was Dante's second lover after Hohenheim
- Lust was Scar's brother's wife

As far as Gluttony and Pride, I think Dante made them just to help her to obtain the philosophers stone.

Gluttony can create red stones (incomplete philosophers stones) which are needed to make a complete philosophers stone and to keep the homunculi alive.

Pride infiltrates the military and start wars, which helps with the collecting of mass amounts of souls, and in pushing people to create a philosophers stones in self defense.

Answer was based off of the 2003 anime.